# Help in Linear summation of n(any given number)

Tags: calculus, summation, nonlinear-optimization

The original formula is this. [image]

We're computing the complexity of an insertion sort.

[image]

How did the first formula turned into the second formula?

Answer (score 1):

$t_j = 1$ for $j = 2,\ldots,n$, so the sums with $(t_j-1)$ vanish, and $\sum_{j=2}^{n} t_j = n-1$. We then get:

$$\begin{align}
T(n) &= c_1 n + c_2(n-1) + c_4(n-1) + c_5(n-1) + c_8(n-1) \\ &= c_1 n + (c_2 + c_4 + c_5 + c_8)(n-1) \\&= c_1 n + (c_2 + c_4 + c_5 + c_8)n - (c_2 + c_4 + c_5 + c_8) \\&= (c_1 + c_2 + c_4 + c_5 + c_8)n - (c_2 + c_4 + c_5 + c_8) \end{align} $$

Comment: Is this Calculus? What topic is this from derivation came from? I think the author has a weak background in mathematics. maybe we can point out what topic is this. so that he can learn more.

Comment: How did you come up with the solution? is this mathematical induction?

Comment: No...I just moved the terms around. Is there any step you don't understand?

Comment: Can you explain it more concise? for now, everything seems to be vague(sorry weak mathematical background here)also how did c5 turned into n-1?

Comment: $\sum_{j=2}^n t_j$ is the sum $t_2 + t_3 + t_4 + \ldots + t_n$. It is given that all the terms $t_2,t_3,\ldots,t_n$ are equal to $1$. So $\sum_{j=2}^n t_j$ is the sum $1 + 1 + \ldots + 1$, and there are $n-1$ terms. So this sum equals $n-1$. So we can write $c_5(n-1)$ instead of $c_5 \sum_{j=2}^n t_j$. All the other steps are just using distributivity.

Comment: I am starting to get it already thanks. what area of mathematics should I dive in to understand more of these?

Comment: This is mostly elementary algebra.

Comment: One last question. why n - 1? you've stated that there are n terms,  shouldn't it be  simply 'n'? am I missing something?

Comment: You start counting at $2$.

Comment: Oh shoot, didn't see that. so if we started counting at 1 and there 5 items. it would be simple just 5?

Comment: Yes, then it would be $5$.